# How to filter a search result in React with filter button?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I filter a search result using react and firebase?

I have this code working fine, each time I type a letter it will show my firebase data search result

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import firebase from './Firebase';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('Products');
    this.unsubscribe = null;
    this.state = {
      filter: "",
      Products: []
    };
  }

  onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const Products = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { title, status } = doc.data();
      Products.push({
        key: doc.id,
        doc, // DocumentSnapshot
        title,
        status
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      Products
   });
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ filter: event.target.value });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
  }

  render() {
    const { filter, Products } = this.state;
    const lowercasedFilter = filter.toLowerCase();
    const filteredData = Products.filter(item => {
      return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
        typeof item[key] === "string" && item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
      );
    });

    return (
      <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">

          <input value={filter} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Search Book"/>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-stripe">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {filteredData.map(item => (
                  <tr>
                    <td><Link to={`/show/${item.key}`}>{item.title}</Link></td>
                    <td>{item.status}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

but now I want to add another filter, to specificly filter the book by it's status from my firebase `{Product.status}`.

something like this,

```html
<input value={filter} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Search Book"/>
<select className="ml-2 mb-2">
 {this.state.Products.map(Products => (
  <option onClick={???}>{Products.status}</option>
 ))};
</select>
```

How can I do it?? what should I write here `onClick={???}` to make the result only show the selected status and keyword typed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an array search based on the collection's node value like this

```
const thfilteredData = firebase_data.filter(({name}) => {
name = name.toLowerCase();
       return name.includes(value.toLowerCase());
   });
setFiltredRestaurants(thfilteredData);
```

I have used the name to match the name value of the child node. You can put it onChange of the search input or for the onClick you can just create a function and pass the option value to match. In your case this could like below.

```
filterProducts = (status) => {
    const thfilteredData = Products.filter(({productstatus}) => productstatus === status);
    this.setState({
        filteredData: thfilteredData
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tareq, but I'm a very beginner here in react, not really mastering most of the command in react. Could you please write me the whole code, so I can learn what to replace. I really appreciate if you do.

Comment: @RedFrog I have updated my answer with status checking. But this is not good to just copy and pest. So please use the updated second example and try to use it with your code.

Comment: @RedFrog One more thing use onChange event for your select to get the selected option value and call the function to update your filtered products.

Comment: @RedFrog Could you please post the solution to your question as an answer and accept it? This measure will increase visibility for future users looking for similar questions. Thanks in advance!